# Entity Framework: accessing associations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My domain model with associations is as follows:

- `Project` has many `Task`s
- `Task` has many `User`s

Depending on the state of a `User`, I need to update a field in the project. My query is as follows:

```
var projects = from project in _data.projects
               join task in _data.tasks on project.ProjectID equals task.ProjectID
               join user in _data.usersactive on task.TaskID equals user.TaskID
               where user.Active == false
               select project;
```

This allows me to get the projects that have users that are inactive.

```
foreach (Project project in projects)
{
    bool needUpdate = false;

    foreach (Task task in project.tasks)
    {
        foreach (User user in task.users)
        {
            // Depending on state of user
            // needUpdate = true;
        }
    }

    // If needUpdate = true
    // Do something
}
```

Obviously this code is going to get me:

`There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.`

I am on MySQL however, and as such am not able to simply leverage `MultipleActiveResultSets=True`.

How would I be able to eagerly load these associations and have them accessible in the `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eagerly load a linq set:

```
var projects = (from project in _data.projects
               join task in 
                       _data.tasks on project.ProjectID equals task.ProjectID
               join user in 
                       _data.usersactive on task.TaskID equals user.TaskID
               where user.Active == false
               select project).ToList();
```

Comment: That turned out to be surprisingly easy, considering the amount of documentation Microsoft has on eager loading. Thanks!